# SmartNavigation issue in .Net 1.1 asp.net app

Tags: html

I have a .Net 1.1 webapp with a aspx page with the attribute SmartNavigation=true set.

I have a anchor in the page like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="$.copy('ANNUAL PAID OZ');">Copy to clipboard</a>
```

Problem is when I click it the browser window scrolls to top.

Any ideas why??

Malcolm

Comment: by the way, this is not an asp.net question - the page would behave the same, no matter how it was generated. You should probably re-tag it to html and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it's a link.
try:

```
<a href='#' onclick="$.copy('string'); return false;">Copy to clipboard</a>
```

(or better, use a function to do it, and bind it using jQuery. But this works too.)